# OpenCV with libav for codecs on Amazon EC2 AMI

Tags: opencv, amazon-ec2, libav

We have an application that requires opencv in a recent version with pkg-config visibility and shared libraries to build. However, the Amazon EC2 AMI instances we are deploying on does not include the yum packages for codecs nor the opencv package.

Other pages describe how to use centOS og rpm packages to get to a working installation. We need a clean install with no yum/rpm cross over.

Answer (score 0):

These steps are most likely one of the shorter paths to the target. Starting directory location is irrelevant as first line ensures a sane (~/build) initial working directory:

```
cd ~/ && mkdir build && cd build/
sudo yum install git cmake gcc-c++
```

Build libav for the codecs (the --prefix option is probably not necessary, but this is the tested and working version)

```
wget https://libav.org/releases/libav-12.3.tar.xz
tar xzf libav-12.3.tar.gz
mkdir libav-12.3-build && cd libav-12.3-build
/home/ec2-user/build/libav-12.3/configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --disable-static
make && sudo make install
```

The amazon default pkg-config thing-a-magic does not look at all standard paths so the next lines symlinks the relevant *.pc files to a location where pkg-config (used by opencv) can find them.

```
cd /usr/share/pkgconfig
for t in `find /usr -name "libav*.pc"`; do sudo ln -s $t .; done
cd ~/build
```

The libav shared libraries have to be available to the linker as well

```
echo /usr/lib/ > libav.conf
sudo mv libav.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
sudo ldconfig
```

Check the pkg-config libav availability by the command

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

and check that the libavcodec, libavformat, libav... etc. packages are listed.

At this point the opencv library can be built and installed with the default tooling

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
mv opencv opencv.git
cd opencv.git/
git branch -r
git checkout 3.4
cd .. && mkdir opencv && cd opencv
cmake ../opencv.git/ && make && sudo make install
cd ..
```

The final binary requires the linker path to contain the '''/usr/local/lib64''' path.

```
echo /usr/local/lib64 > opencv.conf
sudo mv opencv.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
sudo ldconfig
```

The last trick is to enable pkg-config for opencv as well

```
cd /usr/share/pkg-config && ln -s `find /usr/local/ -name "opencv.pc"` . && cd ~/build
```

Check the pkg-config availability by the command

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

and check that opencv is listed.

Done